# RStudio - is there a way to prevent editor from jumping to the bottom when running code?

Tags: r, user-interface, rstudio

With the option "allow scroll past end of document" on, I like to keep my last line of code in the middle of the editor window, but the last line jumps to the bottom of the screen when I run a line of code. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Before running code:

[image]

After running code:

[image]

After running a line of code, I'd like for the window to still look like the first image.

Comment: I can't reproduce it neither on RStudio v1.4.1103 nor 2022.01.0 Build 183.  Are you sure it is enough just to 'run code' to reproduce? At the console?  A year ago I opened a similar undesired-auto-scrolling issue, tracked here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8789
 but I doubt it's the same one.